# jqGrid datatype fybction

Tags: types, jqgrid

When I using datatype: function, and try to check page number, every string of code incrementing page number:

```
                datatype: function (postdata) {
                alert(postdata.page); //1
                alert(postdata.page); //2
                var t = 1;
                alert(postdata.page); //3
            }
```

What does ot means? How get page number in this datatype?

Comment: Which fork of jqGrid (jqGrid version <4.7.1, Guriddo jqGrid JS, free jqGrid) and which version you use? Why you need to use `datatype`? Could you provide the demo which reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm using lates version: jqGrid 4.8.0, I had to use datatype, because ony by it i can make a normal request to server(server dos not support JSON requests) and by datatype: function i can make a paging

Comment: What you want to do inside of `datatype`? I ask you because 99% of code which uses `datatype` as function do it in a wrong way and one can use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` instead. Do you want to make `jQuery.ajax` with some parameters to communicate with the server or not? Moreover I ask you to provide the demo where `alert(postdata.page)` would increment `alert(postdata.page)` like your wrote in the question. Could you provide the demo?

Comment: I can not make easy ajax request with parametrs to communicate with server, that is why I'm using datatype as function for creating request to server and represent data. Not only alert incrementing page, any code operation incrementing it.

Comment: Oleg, I checked - increment going on only in 'debug mode(f12)' in IE. When I'm using it in real work - it works fine.

Comment: You should verify where you have some expression in watch window which increment `postdata.page`.

Comment: Could you include the code of `datatype` function which shows what you need to do to communicate with the server?